# How to selectively add padding for one of the child div without affecting the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have two divs inside a parent div. Something like

```
 <div className='parent'>
    <div className='child1'>
    <div className='child2'>
 </div>
```

I want to achieve something like this [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQTlr.png). How can I add padding only for child2 and not child1. Or is there any other way to do it.

Comment: You could use nth-child: `.parent div:nth-child(2) {padding: 10px}`

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem? Add margins to `.child2`.

```css
.parent > div {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child2 {
  margin: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child1'></div>
    <div class='child2'></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select specific child by nth-child selector, without having to assigning class name to each child seperately.

```
.parent .child:nth-child(2){padding: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give him a specific id or  specific class

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

and in css

```
#div3{
color:red;
}
```